# Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, function

For example;

```
var s = "function test(){
  alert(1);
}";

var fnc = aMethod(s);
```

If this is the string, I want a function that's called fnc. And `fnc();` pops alert screen.

`eval("alert(1);")` doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I added a jsperf test for 4 different ways to create a function from string :

- Using RegExp with Function class

  `var func = "function (a, b) { return a + b; }".parseFunction();`
- Using Function class with "return"

  `var func = new Function("return " + "function (a, b) { return a + b; }")();`
- Using official Function constructor

  `var func = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b;");`
- Using Eval

  `eval("var func = function (a, b) { return a + b; };");`

http://jsben.ch/D2xTG

2 result samples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @KthProg Chill down ;). It's not always bad, like this situation, the jsperf is down at the moment, luckily I added the result screenshots before it was down, when I got the comment from Bulk.

Comment: @KthProg FYI this was a canned response generated by the moderation system :) it pops up in a queue and we check for predetermined problems, one of which this comment is designed to fix. It's not a hard and fast rule, and you'll notice the comment is in the form of a suggestion not a command.

Answer (score 204):

A better way to create a function from a string is by using `Function`:

```
var fn = Function("alert('hello there')");
fn();
```

This has as advantage / disadvantage that variables in the current scope (if not global) do not apply to the newly constructed function.

Passing arguments is possible too:

```
var addition = Function("a", "b", "return a + b;");
alert(addition(5, 3)); // shows '8'
```

Comment: Agree, with `Function` you don't pollute the local scope and this is why `eval` makes optimization so hard for engines... With the OP example, I would: `var fnc = Function('return '+s)();`

Comment: I think this probably should be the accepted answer. It's much safer than eval().

Comment: You, my friend, deserve many upvotes.  This has the advantage of creating a function object which can be assigned to events, etc.  For example: element.onclick = Function("alert('test');");

Comment: @RyanGriggs In your case you do not need the "eval" functionality so it is better written as `element.onclick = function() { alert("test"); }`.

Comment: You are correct from my example.  However, if you wanted to assign arbitrary functions stored in strings, your method is perfect.  This is what I'm actually trying to do.  I have multiple functions stored in string variables, and want to assign one to an onclick action.

Answer (score 40):

You're pretty close.

```
//Create string representation of function
var s = "function test(){  alert(1); }";

//"Register" the function
eval(s);

//Call the function
test();
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/NaMuc/).

Comment: i knew that the function was declared, but couldnt guess to call function name. Thanks alot.

Comment: Obligatory `eval` warning to future searchers: `eval` can open loopholes for hackers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval but if you know its dangers and can avoid them, then this is a nice simple way to create a function from a string

Comment: what if you don't have the name of function since it came from a database record?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, using `Function` is a great solution but we can go a bit further and prepare universal parser that parse string and convert it to real JavaScript function...

```
if (typeof String.prototype.parseFunction != 'function') {
    String.prototype.parseFunction = function () {
        var funcReg = /function *\(([^()]*)\)[ \n\t]*{(.*)}/gmi;
        var match = funcReg.exec(this.replace(/\n/g, ' '));

        if(match) {
            return new Function(match[1].split(','), match[2]);
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

examples of usage:

```
var func = 'function (a, b) { return a + b; }'.parseFunction();
alert(func(3,4));

func = 'function (a, b) { alert("Hello from function initiated from string!"); }'.parseFunction();
func();
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/xck9tvnc/3/) is jsfiddle

Comment: hi please support arrow function support to this method?

Comment: I'm receiving this error in typescirpt 
"Property 'parseFunction' does not exist on type 'String'."

Answer (score 14):

## Dynamic function names in `JavaScript`

### Using `Function`

```
var name = "foo";
// Implement it
var func = new Function("return function " + name + "(){ alert('hi there!'); };")();
// Test it
func();
// Next is TRUE
func.name === 'foo'
```

Source: http://marcosc.com/2012/03/dynamic-function-names-in-javascript/

### Using `eval`

```
var name = "foo";
// Implement it
eval("function " + name + "() { alert('Foo'); };");
// Test it
foo();
// Next is TRUE
foo.name === 'foo'
```

### Using `sjsClass`

https://github.com/reduardo7/sjsClass

#### Example

```
Class.extend('newClassName', {
    __constructor: function() {
        // ...
    }
});

var x = new newClassName();
// Next is TRUE
newClassName.name === 'newClassName'
```

Answer (score 8):

This technique may be ultimately equivalent to the eval method, but I wanted to add it, as it might be useful for some.

```
var newCode = document.createElement("script");

newCode.text = "function newFun( a, b ) { return a + b; }";

document.body.appendChild( newCode );
```

This is functionally like adding this <script> element to the end of your document, e.g.:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript">
function newFun( a, b ) { return a + b; }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `new Function()` with a return inside and execute it immediately.

```js
var s = `function test(){
  alert(1);
}`;

var new_fn = new Function("return " + s)()
console.log(new_fn)
new_fn()
```

Answer (score 2):

An example with dynamic arguments:

```
let args = {a:1, b:2}
  , fnString = 'return a + b;';

let fn = Function.apply(Function, Object.keys(args).concat(fnString));

let result = fn.apply(fn, Object.keys(args).map(key=>args[key]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function expression that is in string form and you want to make it a function, then you need to include a return statement in the string you pass to `new Function`.

```
const strFn = "const sum = (a, b) => a + b"

const newFn = new Function(`${strFn}; return sum`)();

console.log(newFn(2, 3)) // 5
```

If you don't execute immediately, you can use the `function.call` method to execute. Remember the first argument it takes is the `this` value

```
const newFn = new Function('const arrMultiplier = (arr) => arr.map(num => num * 2); return arrMultiplier')
console.log(newFn.call({}).call({}, [6, 4, 1, 0])); // [12, 8, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should simply use **eval** and not use function key word and function name that will be like this

```
var s = `()=>{
   alert(1);
}`;

var fnc = eval(s);
```

eval function returns the function into fnc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval : "Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval()"