# Build javascript chain as text but execute as script

Tags: javascript

I'm working with [this print library](https://github.com/xseignard/thermalPrinter).  What I'm trying to do now is build up my `print` payload.  Right now when it's no dynamic it looks like this:

```
serialPort.on('open',function() {
var printer = new Printer(serialPort);
printer.on('ready', function() {
    printer
        .printLine('text line 1')
        .printLine('text line 2')
        .printLine('text line 3')
        .print(function() {
            console.log('done');
            //do other stuff
        });
});
});
```

The issue I'm having is figuring out how to build up my print payload so that I can dynamcially create my string of `.whatever().whatever().print()`
to actually do the printing.

I ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript) and came up with the following code but get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: printLine is not defined` which makes sense but I don't really know where to go from here.

So.....Basically what I'm asking is, what's a good way to build up a chained function call without it actually being executed as javascript until I trigger it?

```js
var buildLine = Function("input", "printLine('input')");
var lineItems = ['hello', 'world'];
var printPayload = '';
_.map(lineItems, function(item) {
  printPayload += buildLine(item)

})
console.log(printPayload);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [There is always eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but I can't say I recommend it.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing `.whatever().whatever().print()`; some are much larger security holes than others, if you're including user-provided values, or values from outside libraries (or even including things, just on the page, like banner ads); do you have an *exact*, *concrete example* of **what you want to provide, how you want to chain it, and what you want it to print, based on the input and instructions**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is confusing, and seems a bit like an X/Y problem.

I think you want to just store the object in a variable, and then chain on another function at a later time

```
serialPort.on('open', function() {

    var printer = new Printer(serialPort),
        intance;

    printer.on('ready', function() {
        intance = printer.printLine('text line 1')
                         .printLine('text line 2')
                         .printLine('text line 3');
    });

    something.on('later_event', function() {
        instance.print(function() {
            // done
        });
    });
});
```

And looking at the plugin, it has a `commandQueue` where it stores all added commands, so you don't really have to store anything, each instance keeps track of the added commands automatically

```
serialPort.on('open', function() {

    var printer   = new Printer(serialPort);
    var lineItems = ['hello', 'world'];

    printer.on('ready', function() {

        lineItems.forEach(function(line) {

             printer.printLine(line);

        });

    });

    something.on('later_event', function() {
        printer.print(function() {
            // done
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Right, that makes more senses, but how do I build up the "string" of function calls that comprise `intance` ? Because intance needs to be created dynamically.