# turn string into executable function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = ['abc','xyz'];

$.each(arr, function(i,val){
var val = val; //where I got abc, xyz here
if(some condition){
   //run abc function but I don't want to do abc(), possible?
}

});

function abc(){}
function xyz(){}
```

Instead of hardcode my function name like abc(), is there anywhere I can turn string (val) into executable function? by that way I can execute whatever function by just adding values in my array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in a string, just pass in a reference to the function itself:

```js
var arr = [abc, xyz];

$.each(arr, function(i, fn) {
  if (true) {
    fn();
  }
});

function abc() {
  console.log('abc');
}

function xyz() {
  console.log('xyz');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but what does if(true) do there?

Comment: Nothing. I just put it there because you had `if (some condition)` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functions are in the global scope, you can access them through `window[functionname]()`:

```js
var arr = ['abc','xyz'];

$.each(arr, function(i,val){
  window[val]();
});

function abc() {
  console.log('In abc()');
}

function xyz(){
  console.log('In xyz()');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions should be a part of a common parent object. So that can be accessed by their property name.
Here both are part of the `window` Object.

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];

$.each(arr, function(i, val) {
  if (true) { // some condition.
    window[val]();
  }

});

function abc() {
  console.log('Inside the FN abc');
}

function xyz() {
  console.log('Inside the FN xyz');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

eval(str) will run code that is in the string str. You really need to trust str and make sure that users can get access to it.