# Creating functions from strings with events

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I have the following function that should create a function from a String with event -

```
function getFuncDefEvent(jsFunctionString){
    if(jsFunctionString!= undefined) {
        return function(event){jsFunctionString};
    }
}
```

this would be an example of a function string :

```
 jsFunctionString = "doSomething(event); doSomethingElse();
```

I've attached it to a `onclick` event however it doesn't seem to fire any of the events. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you expect a String to do? I suspect you'd need to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for this, but it does have its security problems with untrusted code (and any user-accessible, user-editable, code is or should be untrusted). Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you create a function from a string. You need to use the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```
return new Function(['event'], jsFunctionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:
On review, I think Barmar's answer is probably more correct than my answer below.  I'll leave it for posterity, but his is probably the one that should be selected as correct.

---

---

---

That's not how Javascript works.  If you want to evaluate arbitrary strings as Javascript code you'll have to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).  Please note, however, that much of the prevailing wisdom is that [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).