# Convert string array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
["[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]","[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"]
```

How can I convert that into something like this?

```
[[Date.UTC(2016,09,27),256100.83],[Date.UTC(2016,09,25),261091.57],[Date.UTC(2016,09,23),261391.58]]
```

I am trying this in AngularJS.

Comment: That second line isn't valid JS. You can get the resulting timestamps in the array, but not that.

Comment: `arrayVar.toString()` use for this

Comment: @Cerbrus Right, but i need it in that style for plotting in highcharts.

Comment: Does highcharts require JS date objects there? Or the timestamps?

Comment: @Cerbrus Date object is needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: @Mr.George: That's not the same at all...

Comment: @Mr.George Wow, thats a great catch

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

It's not pretty, but it works, and it doesn't use `eval`.

```js
var a = ["[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]","[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"];
var result = a.map(function(element){
    var row = JSON.parse(element.replace('Date.UTC(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/,0/g, ','));
    return [new Date(row[0], row[1], row[2]), row[3]];
});
console.log(result);
```

This returns the array, with the dates as JS `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const inputs = [
  "[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]",
  "[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", 
  "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"
]

const result = inputs.map(item => {
  const trimItem = item
    .replace('[Date.UTC(', '')
    .replace(']', '')
    .replace(')', '')
  
  const trimItems = trimItem.split(',')
  
  const YYYY = trimItems[0]
  const MM = trimItems[1]
  const DD = trimItems[2]
  const result = [
     Date.UTC(YYYY, MM, DD),
     Number(trimItems[3])
  ]
  
  return result
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution using some regex :) I wonder if month starts with zero or one as index! Javascript date takes month with zero index.

```js
console.log(["[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]","[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"].map(function(i){
  var afloat;
  var date = /Date\.UTC\((\d{4}),(\d{2}),(\d{2})\)/.exec(i);
  date = new Date(Date.UTC(+date[1], +date[2] - 1, +date[3]));
  afloat = +i.split('),')[1].split(']')[0];
  return [date, afloat];
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]","[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"]

var parseItem = function(it) {
    var utcDateReplaced = it.replace(/Date\.UTC\((.*)\)/, function() {
      argsRaw = arguments[1];
      args = argsRaw.split(',');
      return Date.UTC.apply(Date, args);
    })

    return JSON.parse(utcDateReplaced);
}

var result = data.map(parseItem);
console.log(result); 
// ===> [[1477785600000, 250500], [1477699200000, 255100.83], [1477612800000, 255600.82]]
```

http://jsbin.com/kohexuh/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

Between georg's [eval answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759499/893578) and Cerbrus's [replace answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759321/893578), there is a middle ground that works *like* `eval` but does *not* use `eval`: `new Function`

```js
var from = ["[Date.UTC(2016,09,30),250500.00]","[Date.UTC(2016,09,29),255100.83]", "[Date.UTC(2016,09,28),255600.82]"];
var to = from.map( e => new Function( 'return'+e )() ) // To array
             .map( ([a,b]) => [new Date(a), b] ); // date to Date

console.log( to );
```

This is not safe, obviously, but it is short and does not have the other penalties that often comes with `eval`.

Comment: Nice way to hide yourself from eval cops, but still `new Function` is just eval is disguise.

Comment: @georg new Function does evaluate any string you provide, but it doesn't leak scopes like eval, and thus will not pollute them.  Scope access is the main reason eval make the whole script slow, because eval affects other code too, not only itself.