# save full javascript objects to a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

We can load javascript into the browser with javascript through dynamically created `<script>` tags and we can load javascript in node with the `require` method.

The code loaded in these methods can contain fully functional objects with methods in addition to properties.

Is it possible to save javascript code into a file that can then be loaded as mentioned above?

E.g., where `dump_to_file` is the functionality i am looking for,

```
var target_object = {foo : "bar", say_foo : function(){ console.log(this.foo) }  
target_object.say_foo(); // "bar"
dump_to_file("path/to/file.js", target_object)
```

and later, where `load_from_file` is a utility defined in the first paragraph,

```
var target_object = load_from_file("path/to/file.js");
target_object.say_foo(); // "bar"
```

Comment: That is completely impossible; what if it references live objects? (eg, a socket)

Comment: @SLaks I am not familiar with sockets so I can not comment on that precisely. I am curious as to why Python can accomplish this however (e.g., the `pickle` library) while JS can not. I am confident that Python supports the creation of sockets as well.

Comment: What happens if you pickle an active HTTP response?

Comment: Are you asking about how to save a state?

Comment: The general problem is that there is no good way to serialize a function.

Comment: You should use JSON.

Comment: @BrokenRobot not only a state but an arbitrary object with methods as well.

Comment: @SLaks JSON does not support storing methods / functions

Comment: Yes; you shouldn't do that.  That's generally a bad idea; you should separate your code & data.  For example, what if you change a function?

Comment: adding functions dynamically scares me but i guess you could store the guts in a json object and then call it using new Function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: For explanatory reasons you can do `var stringCode = "console.log('test')"` and then `new Function(stringCode)`. We use this way to load dynamic code from a database and run. Check [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: @SLaks - the purpose would be to cache functional objects to use on the client side - so functions changing would be something thought through before using this "cache". ( the goal is similar to what webpack and browserify do - but with the source objects being loaded into a js context already). P.S., thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @BrokenRobot thank you for the reference. I will keep that in mind but don't think it will solve everything i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```js
    let fs = require("fs");
    //   JSON.stringify() features with extra capabilities
    // - Wraps funcs
    // - upon execution, it expose an object, target, into the scope
    var bundle = function(obj) {
      var type = typeof obj;
      if (type === "string") return "'" + obj + "'";
      if (type === "boolean" || type === "number") return obj;
      if (type === "function") return obj.toString();
      var returnValue = [];
      for (var prop in obj) {
        returnValue.push(prop + ": " + bundle(obj[prop]));
      }
      return "{" + returnValue.join(",") + "}";
    };
    
    var target = {
      foo: "bar",
      say_foo: function() {
        console.log(this.foo);
      }
    };
    
    console.log(bundle(target));
    
    var returnValue = "var target = " + bundle(target);
    fs.writeFileSync("target.js", returnValue);
```

And have a look at [Template Literals in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) these ES2015 features help to generate code very efficiently and painless. [Styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) which uses this feature is one of the best example of it.