# passing JSON with functions via AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Quite simply, I'd like to "re-hydrate" functions which are passed from AJAX, as follows:

```
//AJAX response:
{"foo":"bar","baz":"function(){console.log('I am back working as a function!');}"}
```

And obviously, `baz` should be a function and not a string.  How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but of course we must use the *evil* eval .. use at your own risk!!

```js
var ajaxResponse = {"foo":"bar","baz":"function(){console.log('I am back working as a function!')}", "lambda": "() => console.log('Hello i\\'m a lambda')"};

function isAFunction(v) {
    try {
        eval("var f = " + v);
        return typeof f === "function";
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

var result = Object.entries(ajaxResponse).reduce((obj, [key,value]) => {
      if (isAFunction(value)) {
          eval("obj[key] = " + value);
      } else {
            obj[key] = value;
      }
      return obj;
      
}, {});

result.baz();
result.lambda();
```

Comment: that does work, and I presume it will also hydrate any Objects that are declared inside the function itself.  I am only doing this in an environment with trusted interaction between the client and server

Comment: You might need to play about with the syntax, but yes, it should do that!

Answer (score 2):

As Jozef already suggested you can use `eval()`.

But, if you go through Google you will see that the use of that function is NOT recommended:

1. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/
2. [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)
3. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/
4. [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

As this blog suggests (http://2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html) I would recommend you, to use this:

```js
let json = {"foo":"bar","baz":"function(){console.log('I am back working as a function!');}"};

let func = new Function("console.log('I am back working as a function!');");
func();
```

If you don't have the possibility to change your json you can simply use `str.replace()`.

---

Please keep in mind that arbitrary code could be executed! 
I would **strongly** recommend that you do e.g. sth. like this instead of just responding with a function. By doing the following you would do some sort of whitelisting. So, no matter if the http-response has been manipulated, the attacker can only execute the pre-defined javascript functions.

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('I am back working as a function!');
}

function func2() {
  console.log('another code block');
}

let json = {"foo":"bar","baz":"1"};

switch(json.baz) {
  case "1": func1();break;
  case "2": func2();break;
  default: console.error("Invalid response");
}
```

I hope this helps.