# How to use a function as value in Session storage

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server, session-storage

I want to trigger a function while calling a particular `key` stored in `Session Storage`.

I tried the **code** given below.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user', function myfync{alert("Hi")});
```

But while using the getItem function it is returned to me as a string and the function does not get executed. Is there a workaround to this that I'm missing?

Comment: @weegee it's not a duplicate since the question is broader than that single step, it's about sessionstorage value format, consequently converting a function to a string *and* creating a function from a string.

Comment: @seahorsepip the OP knows how to get data from session storage and put in session storage. They don't know how to convert that string to a function _"But while using the getItem function it is returned to me as a string and the function does not get executed"_ It is a clear dupe

Comment: @geewee It's not, the user tries to put a function in sessionstorage and doesn't understand why he gets a string back from sessionstorage instead of a function. Nowhere in the question is mentioned that he expects a string back from sessionstorage instead of a function.

Comment: I was under the assumption that the function should get triggered when getItem is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessionstorage (and localstorage) only support strings as values.

This means you have to convert the value into a string before you store it and convert it back after reading it.

This can be done using String() and Function().

Example:

```
// Write
const a = function myfunc() {
    alert("Hi");
};
sessionStorage.setItem('user', String(a));

// Read
const b = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
const c = Function('return ' + b);

//Execute
c();
```

Converting a string back to a function is a debatable topic, more info can be found here:  [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: I used this code with eval and it works, thank you!

Comment: @seahorsepip Will this work with localStorage? Can't get it to work neither with sessionStorage or localStorage

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage.setItem` will store a `String`, so technically the answer is no. However, you can use a wrapper for `sessionStorage`, like:

```
SessionStorage = {
    setItem: function(key, value) {sessionStorage.setItem(key, value)},
    getItem: function(key) {
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        if (value.startsWith("function")) {
            return eval("(" + value + ")()")
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
SessionStorage.setItem('user', function myfync() {alert("Hi")});
```

and test it like this:

```
SessionStorage.getItem('user');
```

EDIT

I was asked in the comment-section about `localStorage`, so let's implement a wrapper for that as well:

```
LocalStorage = {
    setItem: function(key, value) {localStorage.setItem(key, value)},
    getItem: function(key) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (value.startsWith("function")) {
            return eval("(" + value + ")()")
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
LocalStorage.setItem('user', function myfync() {alert("Hi")});
```

and test it like this:

```
LocalStorage.getItem('user');
```

Comment: This works, but cannot use it for the entire session which was the main reason why I wanted to use sessionStorage in the first place

Comment: @MissXToTheT it can be used in the entire session. Take a look at the code again: it stores into sessionStorage and loads from there as well. The only thing added here is that it checks for a function and executes if it finds it. Normally, you will need to use SessionStorage instead of sessionStorage in order to achieve this.

Comment: @LajosArpad Why doesn't this work for localStorage?

Comment: @Verminous it should work with `localStorage` as well, if you change the references from `sessionStorage` to `localStorage`. The implementation from my answer was focusing on `sessionStorage` and it created a `SessionStorage` object to deal with it. One can implement the same thing for `localStorage` and name it `LocalStorage`.

Comment: @Verminous edited my answer to handle `localStorage` as well. Let me know if it's useful.

Comment: @LajosArpad Actually it worked on my experiments here: https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/b1tdpezf/105/ But it won't work on Chrome Extension I'm working on apparently because ```eval()``` is considered dangerous and Chrome blocks it. Even though I added ```'wasm-unsafe-eval'``` to the manifest. Is there an alternative to ```eval()``` in your wrapper?

Comment: @Verminous Since we are converting text into code, I'm not aware of ways to bypass `eval`. If you provide more information about your specific problem, then there might be a neat solution to that.