# How can I pass a function as a string and chain that string (function) on an object?

Tags: javascript

I have variable `filter` that holds a string that represents a function:

```
const filter = `equalsFilter('elements.url_pattern', ${urlPattern})`
```

I want to chain it on another object like this:

```
query.filter
```

of course, this doesn't work because the filter is a string. Essentially I'm aiming for this result:

```
query.equalsFilter('elements.url_pattern', urlPattern)
```

How can I achieve somewhat like described above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a function from a string with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Why would you have a string of code, where does the string come from? Also, what is `urlPattern`, is it a string literal?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by passing a function representation as an object

```
const filter = {
      type: 'equalsFilter',
      element: 'elements.url_pattern',
      value: urlPattern
    }
```

Then

```
query[filter.type](filter.element, filter.value)
```