# clone object with functions inside

Tags: javascript, object, clone

I am creating a game with many objects, these objects all have their own functions that get called. I have one object that does not do anything and is just for cloning, when this object is cloned everything but the functions get cloned. the x-y gets cloned as well as other this like weight and strength. but the functions don't get cloned. The method I use for cloning is this.

`objects[1] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objects[0]))`

This is not the only clone method I have tried, but all of them gave me the same result. I expect this to clone the object from objects[0] to objects[1] with everything including functions. (they are in an array so I can execute their functions). But only everything but functions are cloned.

Here is an example I made in node.js. (I don't have the anything solid in code as I like to test if it will work before putting it all together).

```js
var original = {};
original.a = true;
original.b = null;
original.c = 82;
original.d = "a string LOL";
original.e = function() {
  console.log("everything does not work?");
}
original.f = [0, "a", true, false];
console.log(original)
console.log(JSON.stringify(original));
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))));
```

Comment: You can't keep functions once converted to JSON, as JSON is a string.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the string is not important, just that the objects don't get cloned, and I showed that what I tried did not work.

Comment: What do you mean the string is not important? It's the reason why using JSON does not work...

Comment: What I mean by the string is not important is that I don't have to use JSON strings, If there was another way, I could do it.

Comment: ah I see. Hopefully the given answers will help you there

Comment: Yeah I did, its working well now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to stringify functions using `JSON.stringify`. Only a subset of primitives are valid JSON. For completeness, function source code can be retrieved with `toString` and [rebuilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript) with the `Function` constructor, but that's messy and unnecessary.

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var original = {};
original.a = true;
original.b = null;
original.c = 82;
original.d = "a string LOL";
original.e = function() {
  console.log("everything does not work?");
}
original.f = [0, "a", true, false];

var copy = Object.assign({}, original);
var spread = {...original};
copy.f = [42, 45];
spread.f = [1, 2];
copy.e();
console.log(original.f, copy.f, spread.f);
```

Note that this isn't a deep (recursive) copy, so if you have nested objects, you'll have a shared alias. See [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) if you want to deep copy.

You also mention you "have one object that does not do anything and is just for cloning". It sounds like you want a class or constructor of some sort. Absent more information, I prefer a function that returns an object and acts as a closure on any hidden properties you might want (you could also use a traditional constructor with `this` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66936937/6243352)):

```js
const makeFoo = () => ({
  a: true,
  b: null,
  c: 82,
  d: "a string LOL",
  e: function () {
    console.log("everything does not work?");
  },
  f: [0, "a", true, false],
});

const foos = [...Array(3)].map(makeFoo);
foos[0].c = 42;
console.log(foos);
```

You can parameterize some or all of these attributes with optional default values:

```js
const makeFoo = props => {
  const defaults = {
    a: true,
    b: null,
    c: 82,
    d: "a string LOL",
    e: function () {
      console.log("everything does not work?");
    },
    f: [0, "a", true, false],
  };
  return {...defaults, ...props};
};

const foos = [...Array(3)].map(() => makeFoo({a: false, b: 5}));
foos[0].c = 42;
console.log(foos);
```

...but I'm speculating a lot on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The best option out there is the `cloneDeep` method offered by [lodash](https://lodash.com). This will clone all primitives and all nested objects, and ofc you won't loose functions declarations

Comment: `cloneDeep` based on https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#clone, it will return empty object for functions

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same structured clone mechanism that the HTML standard includes for sending data between realms: structuredClone

```
const clone = structuredClone(original);
```

Comment: no you cannot b/c OP specifically asked for cloning an object that may have functions as values. `structuredClone()` will throw an error when it encounters a function.