# How to catch a function into a variable and change its code?

Tags: javascript, function

If a variable contains an existing function, how can you replace something inside its code?

It seems `toString()` (in order to replace the string) adds an "extra" `function() { }` and therefore fails.

For example changing test1 into test2 or test3 in:

```js
var theparent = {
  myfunc: function () {
    console.log('test1');
  }
}

console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc();
theparent.myfunc = new Function("console.log('test2')"); // Works
console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc();
theparent.myfunc = new Function(theparent.myfunc.toString().replace('test2', 'test3')); // Adds function() { }
console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc(); // Fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seemed to me ([from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011280/4829915)) was `eval`:

```js
var theparent = {
  myfunc: function () {
    console.log('test1');
  }
}

console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc();
theparent.myfunc = new Function("console.log('test2')"); // Works
console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc();
eval("theparent.myfunc = " + theparent.myfunc.toString().replace('test2', 'test3')) // does NOT add function() { }
console.log(theparent.myfunc);
theparent.myfunc(); // Finally works
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make the internal function an immediately called function, not a scalable solution though, but try this:

```
var theparent = {
  myfunc: function () {
    console.log('test1');
  }
}

console.log(theparent.myfunc.toString());
theparent.myfunc();
theparent.myfunc = new Function("console.log('test2')"); // Works
console.log(theparent.myfunc.toString());
theparent.myfunc();
theparent.myfunc = new Function("("+theparent.myfunc.toString().replace('test2', 'test3')+")()"); // Adds function() { }
console.log(theparent.myfunc.toString());
theparent.myfunc(); // Works
```