# How to parse a string to a function that expects parameters and returns a value?

Tags: javascript

It is possible to configure functions as strings to parse them to functions during runtime.

The following example `functionAsString` expects input and deals with it, I only know that it MUST return a boolean ( I'm expecting that )

```js
const x = {
  fields: {
    age: 0
  }
};
const y = {
  fields: {
    age: 1
  }
};

const functionAsString = "(left, right) => left.fields.age < right.fields.age";
const compareFunction = new Function(functionAsString);

const isXLessThanY = compareFunction(x, y);

if (isXLessThanY === undefined) {
  console.error("it should not be undefined...");
} else {
  console.log({
    isXLessThanY
  });
}
```

`isXLessThanY` is `undefined`. Do you know how to setup a valid function based on a string?

Comment: It would need to be `new Function("left", "right", "return left.fields.age < right.fields.age")`, but that's almost just as bad as using `eval()` and can be a security risk if these strings are user provided. What is the reason why you need to have the function as a string in the first place?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650071/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-from-a-string-with-javascript) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Function` constructor actually takes more structured data than `eval`, it takes the parameter names, then the body. Also it does generate a regular function (not an arrow function) so you have to explicitly `return`.

```js
const x = {
  fields: {
    age: 0
  }
};
const y = {
  fields: {
    age: 1
  }
};

const functionAsString = "return left.fields.age < right.fields.age";
const compareFunction = new Function('left', 'right', functionAsString);

const isXLessThanY = compareFunction(x, y);

if (isXLessThanY === undefined) {
  console.error("it should not be undefined...");
} else {
  console.log({
    isXLessThanY
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eval()` function to run js code as a string, but it has some security issues.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: yes, but I thought the "never use eval" section shows that `Function` is a valid alternative

Comment: problem might be the arrow function in functionAsString, have you try the normal function declaration ?

Comment: you mean like so? https://jsfiddle.net/f0e2wnLj/ this syntax didn't work for me